# How to test mysqli's real_escape_string()?

Tags: security, mysqli, sql-injection

I'm fairly new to mysqli (not to mysql!) and I'm updating a currently-mysql-function which secures a string (or an (recursive) array with strings) for basic sanitation.

The [php.net mysqli::real_escape_string() manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) has a very clear warning about that charset. I've implemented this.

How do I test this? I can't find the information I'm looking for. I guess I'm looking for certain strings to input resulting in an unsecure result, and a result considered save.

I don't mean "add slashes to ' <- those single quotes". I'm looking for some more advanced tricks or vulnerabilities.

I'm also not looking for prepared statements. Those are wonderful and ***I'd love to use those***, but not an option at this point because updating I'm a old system as fast as possible, prepared statements are not an option at this point in time. I'll be adding those in the future.

Comment: -1 for "I am not looking for prepared statements". Because you should

Comment: That makes no sense... Im working on an existing system, at this point I can't do this, that would be too much work. As I stated; they're wonderfull, but not at this moment. This would be a next-round update, I'm planning to do so in new code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here is the code you are looking for](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5133221/285587), I believe. Just change mysql to mysqli.

Also please note that

- this function is not to "secure" strings but to **format** them. Means every string that is going into query have to be processed, no matter if you count it "dangerous" or not.
- this function have to be used to format SQL **string** literals **only**. And it is utterly useless for all other query parts.
- this function **should not** to be used in the application code, but to support [emulated prepared statements **only**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14171484/285587).

Anyway, if your database encoding is conventional `utf-8`, there is no point to bother with encoding at all. "A clear warning" actually connected to some marginal and extremely rarely used encodings only.

Comment: +1 for the explanation and the `utf-8` remark. I'm looking for something more broad to test. For eample an list of strings which breaks stuff. Those examples are handled just fine in my utf8 system :)

Comment: That's what I am talking about. There are no such strings exist. "A clear warning" just inapplicable for utf-8.

Comment: Oh, like that. Ok, thats good to know. Im pretty same at this moment than. Slowly going to migrate to the prepared statemants